# Sequential learning, reference request.

Tags: statistics, reference-request, machine-learning

I would like to find a book (or link) for a master math student about the following topics.

I don't know the field and I don't want to be lost in details so it should be a straightforward resource, please.

I'm a math student but I would like to apply myself to artificial intelligence, so I would like the books to be applied and contain images. Illustrations (graph of function, schema) are important to me, as well as examples and remarks.

> 1) Learning with expert advices, adversarial environment, mirror
>   descent.
>
> 2) Learning in an unknown environment, exploration/exploitation
>   trade-off, information-theoretic lower bounds.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are lists of books and papers which you may helpful.

Introductory books:

- [Introduction to artificial intelligence and expert systems](http://182.160.97.198:8080/xmlui/handle/123456789/914)
- [Introduction to artificial intelligence](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=vC-oDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA33&dq=introduction%20to%20%20artificial%20intelligence&ots=XK023HCCxp&sig=RzpoO9d8ZpTJr5mZ6sCDKaEu7CI#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20%20artificial%20intelligence&f=false)
- [Artificial intelligence: a modern approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)
- [Principles of artificial intelligence](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=mT-jBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=%20artificial%20intelligence&ots=hL1ifM0Hch&sig=mYfXwoy4j35EakZRUUxoOQWk1gE#v=onepage&q=artificial%20intelligence&f=false)
- [The handbook of artificial intelligence](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=xP7iBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=%20artificial%20intelligence&ots=KapVZ-0sW7&sig=7kfEJ-hYzdRwDwxjZOEaXS8R_xc#v=onepage&q=artificial%20intelligence&f=false)
- [An artificial intelligence approach](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-12405-5)
- [Logical foundations of artificial intelligence](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=nFktBAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=%20artificial%20intelligence&ots=Zz88Cn9H_N&sig=stBm0dY-oZqTo4kz-9-zif5ZOCc#v=onepage&q=artificial%20intelligence&f=false)

More specialized sources:

- [Adversarial reinforcement learning](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/anon/usr0/ftp/usr/ftp/2003/CMU-CS-03-107.pdf)
- [Minimax policies for adversarial and stochastic bandits](https://hal-enpc.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00834882/)
- [Design of network topology in an adversarial environment](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-17197-0_1)
- [Mirror descent](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33&q=artificial%20intelligence%20mirror%20descent&btnG=)
- [The information geometry of mirror descent](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7004065)
- [Path planning approach in unknown environment](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11633-010-0508-6)
- [How to learn an unknown environment](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/185382)
- [Impedance learning for robots interacting with unknown environments](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6654275)
- [Exploitation trade-off](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33&q=exploitation%20trade-off&btnG=)
- [Surpassing the information theoretic bound with fusion trees](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000093900404)
- [An information theoretic lower bound for the longest common subsequence problem](http://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/19954/Hir1977Apr9AnInforma.PDF?sequence=1)
- [Information-theoretic lower bounds on the oracle complexity of convex optimization](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3689-information-theoretic-lower-bounds-on-the-oracle-complexity-of-convex-optim)

Comment: They are really old !

Comment: @CechMS But you wanted introductory references, right?